# C: _Generic fallback for all pointer types

Tags: c, generics

I have a C macro which is similar to this one:

```
#define F(x)                  \
  _Generic((x),    int:    1, \
                  char:    2, \
                char *:    3, \
           const int *:    4  \
  )
```

However, I would like to have a branch which applies for all remaining pointer types (e.g. `short *` or `const struct bla *`). Is that possible? I tried using `const void *`, but that does not work.

If not, is it possible to define that the default-branch should output some nice readable error? I tried `default: static_assert(0, "Blabla")`, but then the assertion is also evaluated, even if the branch is not taken.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use a separate `_static_assert(_Generic((x), int: 1, char: 1 …, default: 0), "Unexpected type");`, then have the `_Generic` you want after that. `_Generic` matches to a compatible type, and there is no type that is compatible with all pointer types. Even if there were, only one of the items is allowed to be a compatible type, so there is no way to say “any pointer type other than the previous ones,” except for the `default` case. So catching the default case may be the best you can do.

Comment: It would be nice to have the `_Generic` association list support special keywords such as `struct` and `pointer` that would match to any struct and any pointer, respectively, after all types have been tested, but before applying `default`.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would like to have a branch which applies for all remaining pointer types (e.g. `short *` or `const struct bla *`). Is that possible?

Not as such.  The type names in the generic association list of a `_Generic` expression must designate complete object types, and they match only expressions expressions of compatible type (in the language spec's sense of "compatible").  There is no type that is compatible with all pointer types in this sense, and if there were, then using it as one of the type names in a `_Generic` expression would preclude using any other pointer types as options in the same `_Generic` expression.

Only the `default` option of a `_Generic` expression can match both `short *` and `const struct blah *`, but it would also catch any and all non-pointer types for which no compatible type is is present in the generic association list.  Inasmuch as I understand you to be asking for an option that matches a subset of pointer types but not any non-pointer types, `default` could do that only in a generic selection that has an explicit option compatible with each non-pointer object types.  But that's impossible, because C supports infinitely many non-pointer object types.

> If not, is it possible to define that the default-branch should output some nice readable error?

If you mean that the message should be emitted at runtime, when the generic selection is (formally) evaluated, then sure.  You have the whole world of C I/O options, plus `assert()` if you want program termination along with the message.

But if you mean that a message should be emitted at compile time, as your mention of `_Static_assert` suggests, but only if the controlling expression is matched to the default option, then standard C does not provide any such alternative.  However, that may be overthinking it.  If you provide no `default` option, then it is a constraint violation for the type of the controlling expression to not be compatible with any of the options given, and a conforming compiler must diagnose all constraint violations.  Thus, you get a message for free in that case, though you cannot control the message content.  Whether it constitutes a "nice readable error" depends on your C implementation and on what you consider readable.